# Session and page Redirection Not working on hosted server?

Tags: php

My php website is clearly working on localhost.When  hosted it to server page redirection doesn't works(Tested by removing all echo).But when using javascript redirection it works but missing session variables on the next page.

Then tested echo session_id(); on both pages it show different numbers.How can I solve this issue?
I handle path on server using set_include_path();method.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<?php 
session_start(); 
ob_start(); 
set_include_path(".:/home/user/data"); 
echo session_id(); 
//echo ini_get('session.cookie_domain');
if($id == 'Login failed'){ header("Location: login.php?msg=Invalid Username or Password"); } 
?>
```

Comment: Some code please? What are you using to redirect? `header()`? Also try `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at the beginning of the php page to help you find errors.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<?php session_start(); 
ob_start();
set_include_path(".:/home/user/data");
echo session_id();
//echo ini_get('session.cookie_domain');
?>

Comment: if($id == 'Login failed'){
header("Location: login.php?msg=Invalid Username or Password");
}

Comment: You can edit your post and put the code in that itself. Let me do it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use `session_start()` or `header()` after content has been sent to the browser (`<!DOCTYPE html>` in your case).

Here, even if you are using `ob_start()` to buffer the output, what came before has not been buffered and is sent to the browser, which prevents `header()` and `session_start()`  from working.

From the PHP documentation :

> To use cookie-based sessions, **session_start()** must be called before outputting anything to the browser.
>
> Remember that **header()** must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.

The fact that it works on your local computer but not on your Web hosting provider's server  is most likely due to differences between your configuration of PHP or of your Web server. For instance, output buffering may be enabled by default on your local installation (`output_buffering = 4096` for instance), and be disabled on your Web hosting (`output_buffering = Off`).